# Is there a way to add custom launch arguments for lime? (For example, different game types compiled with "lime test windows -example")

Tags: haxeflixel

I have an idea for a game with multiple types with differences, sharing all the same base code (think Pokemon, but with more difference) is there a way to do that? For example, using `#if example --code-- #end`, like html5/windows specific content? And if so, how would you build it (lime test windows -example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on `lime help`:

> -D*value* -- Specify a define to use when processing other commands

So by executing `lime test windows -Dmydefine` you should then be able to use the compiler define to do [conditional compilation](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-condition-compilation.html) in your code :

```
#if mydefine
// your specific code
#end
```

Is it what you are looking for ?